# Display substring found in string, indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, indexof

I have an array that contains an amount of "substrings":

```
var substrings = ["tomato", "tomato sauce", "tomato paste", "orange", "orange juice", "green apple", "red apple", "cat food"];
```

Then a string such as:

```
var str = "Hunt's 100% Natural Tomato Sauce, 15 Oz";
```

I can find the substring "tomato sauce" within the string using indexOf() and some()

```
if (substrings.some(function(v) {return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) >= 0;}))
{
  // true  
} else {
  //false
}
```

but this just returns a true/false.  I would need to set a variable **matchingSubstring** to the substring that was matched within the string.

```
if(???) {
  var matchingSubstring = substring // tomato sauce
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter it:

```js
var substrings = ["tomato", "tomato sauce", "tomato paste", "orange", "orange juice", "green apple", "red apple", "cat food"];
var str = "Hunt's 100% Natural Tomato Sauce, 15 Oz";

const matches = substrings.filter(function(v) {return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) >= 0;});
if (matches.length > 0)
    console.log(matches.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0]);
else
    console.log("fail");
```

`some` is only useful if you do not need the concrete result items.

Comment: Filter returns multiple (if there are multiple matches) results.  How would I have it return "tomato sauce" since that's the substring that best matches?

Comment: @RyanJay: You could sort by string length and return the first/last item. I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the result

```
substrings.find(function(v) {return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) >= 0;})
```

Note that this will return the first match, if you want to find all matching entries, you could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.